# Why do I have "Filesystem root" logo in desktop after instalation of ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, security

I have installed Ubuntu 18 before, but in the last installation I got this logo in my desktop:

[image: screenshot of desktop]

Is this normal? I'm a little worried that I got hacked.

Answer (score 1):

No, Filesystem Root is just a shortcut to the root directory on your computer. You haven't been hacked.

Comment: But *why* is it there? In a standard installation of Ubuntu 18.04 it doesn't appear afaik.